# Android: Http post with parameters not working

Tags: android, http-post

I need to create an HTTP POST request with parameters. I know there are many examples out there, I have tried using HTTPparams, NameValuePair etc but cant seem to get the correct format for the server.

`Server Type: REST based API utilizing JSON for data transfer

Content-type: application/json

Accept: application/json

Content-length: 47

{"username":"abcd","password":"1234"}`

I can pass these headers but I cant seem to pass these params "username","password". Here is my code:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.mymi5.net/API/auth/login");   
    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","abcd"));  
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password","1234"));  
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs,"UTF-8");  
    post.setEntity(entity);  
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

I tried to debug, but cant see if entity is attached properly or not... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance.
Maaz

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.mymi5.net/API/auth/login");   
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("username", "abcd");
obj.put("password", "1234");
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Comment: perfect - to add, I like to use the defined constant: `HTTP.UTF_8`

Comment: Why does this work and the OP's code doesn't? I'm facing a similar problem but only on 1 out of 10 servers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, from your description, but it would seem that your server expects a JSON content object instead of the data being encoded in the URL. Send something like this as the *body* of your post:

```
{"username":"abcd","password":"1234"}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmon, Femis code worked fine. but even your suggestion would have led me to the right code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.mymi5.net/API/auth/login");   
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  

pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","abcd"));  
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password","1234"));  

UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs,HTTP.UTF_8);  
post.setEntity(entity);  
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

just try this coz it works perfect for me when i am trying to HTTP post.

Comment: Thanks Sumant, I did try this at one stage but did not work. :(

Answer (score 1):

this will probably work for you.

assuming you already have the json object.

NOTE: (1)in the server you need to handle th request as utf-8 (also in the DB).

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static HttpResponse executePostRequest(JSONObject jsonData, String url) {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        httpost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(jsonData.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
        httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        httpost.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        return httpResponse;

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

then in the client handle the server response like this:

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils
                    .toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```