# Cannot receiving JSON data from app

Tags: php, android, json, http-post

Seems Android app sends the JSON Object without problems but when i receive i get a :

"Notice: undefined index"

The Code that sends the Object is here :

```
    public void sendJson( String name1, String name2 ) throws JSONException {


    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/JSON_FOLDER/JSON2/parseData.php");
    HttpResponse response;

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {           
            json.put("name1", name1);
            json.put("name2", name2);

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            httppost.getParams().setParameter("json", json);        // new code 

            //Execute HTTP POST request

            httppost.setEntity(se);
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            if( response != null )  {
                    str =  inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                    Log.i("DATA", "Data send==  " + str );
            }

    } catch ( ClientProtocolException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( IOException e )   {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

On the Server side :

```
$json = $_POST['name1'];
$decoded = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

and i got the undefined index notice.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the raw result replied, either on server or on client side.

Comment: like that : ***file_get_contents('php://input');*** I tried it but there are no results

Comment: ON the server side you dump the reply into a logfile (php syslog() for example). On the client side: depends on your platform, I don't know android. Easiest probably is to use a network sniffer like Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Edit - revising my answer:

It appears you are sending a single parameter called `json` that contains 'name1' and 'name2' as the data.

Something like this should work: On the PHP side you need to decode the JSON first:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['json']);
```

then you can access name1 and name2:

```
$name1 = $json['name1'];
$name2 = $json['name2'];
```

If you still get errors, I suggest printing out the $_POST and $_GET objects and see how your data is being sent. Then you will know how to access it.

---

Update:

the result you're getting `array(0) { }` means PHP did not get any parameters (GET or POST) from your request. You might try a different android example like this one:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://example.com/JSON_FOLDER/JSON2/parseData.php");   
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("name1", name1);
json.put("name2", name2);
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

if( response != null )  {
    str =  inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
    Log.i("DATA", "Data send==  " + str );
}
```

[Reference Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958182/android-http-post-with-parameters-not-working)

Comment: I tried all possible combinations with $_GET, $_POST and with 'json', 'name1', 'name2' and always the result is the same. Undefined index.
I also removed the set 'json' parameter from the app but still the same.

Comment: do a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` it will tell you if any parameters are making it to the PHP code.