# How do I convert this curl request to Apache HttpClient java code?

Tags: java, apache, http, post, http-post

I'm trying to send this in java:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST 'http://www.example.com/foo' -d '{"rootURL": "http://www.subway.com"}'
```

Here's the code I have:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/foo");

    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rootURL", "http://www.subway.com"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
    client.execute(post);
```

but I'm getting a 400 error:

```
Unexpected character ('r' (code 98)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@a18ba7b; line: 1, column: 2]
```

If I change this line:

```
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rootURL", "http://www.subway.com"));
```

to

```
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bootURL", "http://www.subway.com"));
```

I get the following error:

```
Unexpected character ('b' (code 98)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@a18ba7b; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP POST using JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason it works if I replace:

```
List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rootURL", "http://www.subway.com"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
```

with:

```
post.setEntity(new StringEntity("{\"rootURL\":\"http://www.subway.com\"}", "UTF-8"));
```

Here's the link I found this suggestion from, but it doesn't answer why. Can anyone explain why it won't work with UrlEncodedFormEntity?

[Android: Http post with parameters not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958182/android-http-post-with-parameters-not-working)

Comment: My guess is when using UrlEncodedFormEntity the key/value pairs are added into the request URL. However, remote server looks for key/value pair in the request body formatted as json which the StringEntity does.