# Translate curl into java code (Jenkins plugin)

Tags: java, curl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to translate this curl into Java code. Sadly I don't know much of curl :(

```
curl http://myjenkins/job/myjob/lastBuild/api/json | grep --color result\":null
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868189/how-do-i-convert-this-curl-request-to-apache-httpclient-java-code

Comment: You don't need to know much curl. That command is just getting that url and passing it onto the next command grep.

Comment: How can i perform a grep action in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURL is just a client side utility that can manipulate on HTTP responses (very tiny console browser)
Take a look at [JAVA HTTP CLIENT](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) or something similar - that should be easy.

Comment: I know the HTTP Client, but I don't know how I can perform a request which contains true or false. Like grep --color result\":null

Comment: In the topic you've asked about curl - curl is HTTP client. What you're asking about now is **grep**. **GREP** is search utility that will look for string like ** result: null **. Assuming that in response you're expecting JSON result - you will need use any java lib that can parse JSON and then look for expected result, or manually search for ** result : null ** string using java regex.