# how to make WCF service accept 'ÿ' or '�'

Tags: c#, android, json, vb.net, wcf

while am trying to connect android app with wcf service in vb.net
i can send data as well, but if text contain ÿ or � 
i got 400 bad request:
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation. Encountered unexpected character 'ÿ'

android http code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL + "/" + funName);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(post.getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8)));
```

wcf server side:

```
 <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate:="uploadfile")>
```

how can i handle it??

Comment: Can you use Fiddler or Web Dev tools to show us the json object?

Comment: Have you tried changing encoding on WCF server side? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908030/calling-a-webservice-that-uses-iso-8859-1-encoding-from-wcf/1908154#1908154

Comment: @AdrianSzulc not working
anther idea?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958182/android-http-post-with-parameters-not-working